# How to get applied stored procedure for inserted row in mysql php query

Tags: mysql, php, javascript

```
$query = "CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS Insertion(IN firstname varchar(40),IN lastname varchar(40),IN email varchar(40),IN department varchar(40),IN doj date,IN basicpay int(11))
BEGIN
  
  DECLARE HRA decimal(20,2);
  DECLARE DA decimal(20,2);
  DECLARE PF decimal(20,2);
  DECLARE NET_SALARY decimal(20,2);
  
  IF department = 'HUMAN RESOURCE' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  ELSEIF department = 'MARKETING' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  ELSEIF department = 'PRODUCTION' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  ELSEIF department = 'FINANCE AND ACCOUNTING' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  
  ELSE 
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  
  END IF; 
SET NET_SALARY = basicpay+HRA + DA + PF;
    
  insert into employees(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,DEPARTMENT,DATE_OF_JOINING,BASIC_PAY,HRA,DA,PF,NET_SALARY)
  values(firstname,lastname,email,department,doj,basicpay,HRA,DA,PF,NET_SALARY);
  
END";
```

Comment: 1) Always provide complete unchanged error messages when you receive them. 2) Never create variables (including SP parameters) that have the same name as table columns until you become a professional. 3) For shown code - generated columns seems to be enough.

Comment: I suggest having a table keyed by `department` that has the factors.  That would eliminate the clumsy if/then/else.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE PROCEDURE` has no `IF NOT EXISTS`.

You have to drop it and create it a new

Also php and mysqli don't add `DELIMITER` to the `CREATe PROCEDURE`, so you have to do it yourself.

So the code must loook like

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Insertion;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertion(IN firstname varchar(40),IN lastname varchar(40),IN email varchar(40),IN department varchar(40),IN doj date,IN basicpay int(11))
BEGIN
  
  DECLARE HRA decimal(20,2);
  DECLARE DA decimal(20,2);
  DECLARE PF decimal(20,2);
  DECLARE NET_SALARY decimal(20,2);
  
  IF department = 'HUMAN RESOURCE' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  ELSEIF department = 'MARKETING' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  ELSEIF department = 'PRODUCTION' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  ELSEIF department = 'FINANCE AND ACCOUNTING' THEN
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  
  ELSE 
  SET HRA = (5/100)*basicpay;
  SET DA = (7/100)*basicpay;
  SET PF = (10/100)*basicpay;
  
  
  END IF; 
SET NET_SALARY = basicpay+HRA + DA + PF;
    
  insert into employees(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL,DEPARTMENT,DATE_OF_JOINING,BASIC_PAY,HRA,DA,PF,NET_SALARY)
  values(firstname,lastname,email,department,doj,basicpay,HRA,DA,PF,NET_SALARY);  
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```